# Opengraph & Linkedin for multilanguage pages

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, grav

Our company needs to publish a post on Linkedin to the following page, which exists in French and English. Problem: Linkedin recognizes the og:image property in French, but not in English.

**The urls:**
https://www.bsit.com/en/bsit-business (EN)
https://www.bsit.com/fr/bsit-business (FR)
I've set og:image properties on both so that each shows a specific image thumbnail when sharing on social media. The website uses Grav, btw.

**The issue:**
When trying to share the French link on Linkedin, the proper image thumbnail shows up. For the English link, it doesn't show the picture specified in the og:image property but another image use within the landing page.

**What I've tried:**
Adding a random query at the end of the url ('/bsit-business?1') gives the right thumbnail. Adding a '?utm' query (which I'd like to use) doesn't fix the thumbnail, for some reason.
The FR page works fine, so I doubt it's because I didnt include the og prefix on my website...
Images exist, og:image links are correct, dimensions and filesize respect requirements.
Everything works fine on Facebook.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Something I've tried which seems to fix the problem: adding both the random query '?1' query and UTM parameters, to allow both for the thumbnail to appear and the tracking to be done (hopefully). Can't figure out why that is, though.

Anyway since it's quite a clanky fix, I would still appreciate anyone's feedback on the matter! Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem certainly doesn't exist anymore.

- [Share English Language URL](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bsit.com%2Fen%2Fbsit-business)
- [Share French Language URL](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bsit.com%2Fen%2Fbsit-business)

So, what happened?  Probably a caching issue, as LinkedIn likes to cache pages.  You can invalidate the cache by loading up your website in the LinkedIn Post Inspector.

**[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.bsit.com%2Fen%2Fbsit-business)** : This is likely the best tool, as it tells you how everything displays (image, title, url, etc.) and why it made that decision (`og:` tags, title/html tags, other tagging systems, etc.).

If it still doesn't invalidate the cache and reupdate the info available, try checking `example.com?somerandomthing=test`.  Since the URL is technically different, and since you're probably not doing any logic based on `somerandomthing`, this should cause a fresh, pull of the page data for inspecting.